# LogPlot hangs but Plot does not

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

This is a bit involved example, but I have not been able to reproduce it in more simple cases.

```
Print[$Version, $System]
9.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (November 20, 2012)Linux x86 (64-bit)
```

Lets define this function:

```
Clear@ff; ff[d_, x_] = Exp[-d/(1 + x)];
```

Now the idea is to plot this function but with x being the solution to $x=ff[d,x]$.

```
Plot[ff[d,FixedPoint[ff[d, #] &, 0.1, SameTest -> (Abs[1 - #1/#2] < 0.01 &)]], {d, 1, 4}]
```

And worked!

[image: worked!]

But LogPlot (and LogLogPlot and LogLinearPlot) hangs forever..

```
LogPlot[ff[d,FixedPoint[ff[d, #] &, 0.1, SameTest -> (Abs[1 - #1/#2] < 0.01 &)]], {d, 1, 4}]
```

However, if I define

```
zz[d_?NumberQ] :=  ff[d,FixedPoint[ff[d, #] &, 0.1,SameTest -> (Abs[1 -#1/#2] < 0.01 &)]];
```

then it works:

```
LogPlot[zz[d], {d, 1, 4}]
```

[image: works]

Why this happens?

Comment: The `Plot`, `LogPlot`, and `LogLogPlot` versions run equally well and quickly in MMA 10.1 on Win7-64bit. This may be version dependent.

Comment: @MarcoB bummer..

Comment: Everything works fine in Mma 10.1 on Mac OS 10.10.4

Comment: Same issue on Windows 7, 9.01. You can use, e.g., `ListLogPlot[
 Table[{d, 
   FixedPoint[ff[d, #] &, 0.1, 
    SameTest -> (Abs[1 - #1/#2] < 0.01 &)]}, {d, 1, 4, .001}], 
 Joined -> True]`

Answer (score 1):

I do get the same behavior in `10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)Microsoft Windows (64-bit)`. 
How ever, if you run the test for `NumberQ` in the code being evaluated for the plot, the answer pops out:

```
LogPlot[
    If[NumberQ[d]
       , ff[d,FixedPoint[ff[d, #] &
            , 0.1
            , SameTest -> (Abs[1 - #1/#2] < 0.01 &)]
         ]
       ,Print[d];
    ]
    , {d, 1, 4}]
```

It prints out `d` and then does the plot. I don't know why it does that though.